# Error while running requirement.txt

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create **requirement.txt** for my Django project. I went through https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html and accordingly trying to my **requirement.txt**

```
Django==1.8.4
django-autocomplete-light
django-cors-headers
django-watson
django-filter
django-import-export
MySQL-python
Pillow
jsonpickle
mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
python-amazon-product-api
lxml
similarityPy
coverage
django-redis-cache
redis
django-debreach
```

Error which I am getting is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Mon Dec  7 20:36:32 2015
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 262, in run
    for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options, session=session):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1632, in parse_requirements
    req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from, prereleases=getattr(options, "pre", None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 173, in from_line
return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 71, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python', 'at', ' --allow-external mysql-connector-python')
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not valid in a `requirements.txt` file:

```
mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

I think the format for doing this would be:

```
--allow-external mysql-connector-python
mysql-connector-python
```

i.e. something like `--allow-external mysql-connector-python`, which would be a command-line arg to pip itself, should appear on its own line

https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

This is also invalid (!) in a pip requirements file:

```
apt-get install redis-server
```

Comment: yes. i realized `apt-get` later. removed it too. Thanks :)